# flex4 moduls data passing from one module to another module

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a Flex 4 application that loads a two module. first module is user login module and second one is user balance. when user application start login screen is displayed. when user login this module pass to java and process some validations and return to the flex. in flex if user is valid pass that user name to the second module. in that module using that name again pass user name to java and get balance of that user.

but my code is not working?

am tring this code:-

**modules.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"  xmlns:views="views.*">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<views:module2/>
<views:module1>

</views:module1>
</s:Application>
```

**module1.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Module xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

        protected function login_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            if(har.text=="valid"){
                var username:String = "module2.swf?" + "username=" +user.text;
                bordercontainerlogin.visible=false;

            }else if(har.text=="not-valid")
            {
                validation.text="! make sure user name & password correct";         
            }
            else
                validation.text=har.text
        }
        protected function user_focusInHandler(event:FocusEvent):void
        {
            if((user.text=="User name")||(user.text==""))
            {
                user.text="";
            }
        }

        protected function user_focusOutHandler(event:FocusEvent):void
        {
            if((user.text=="User name")||(user.text==""))
            {
                user.text="User name";
            }
        }
        protected function pass_focusInHandler(event:FocusEvent):void
        {
            pass.displayAsPassword=true;
            if((pass.text=="Password")||(pass.text==""))
            {
                pass.text="";
            }
        }
        protected function pass_focusOutHandler(event:FocusEvent):void
        {
            if((pass.text=="Password")||(pass.text==""))
            {
                pass.displayAsPassword=false;
                pass.text="Password";
            }

        }

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(((user.text=="User name")||(user.text=="")) || ((pass.text=="Password")||(pass.text=="")))

            {

                if((user.text=="User name")||(user.text==""))
                {
                    //validation.text="! Make sure user name shouidn't be empty";
                    Alert.show(user.text);                  }

                else if((pass.text=="Password")||(pass.text==""))
                {
                    validation.text="! Make sure Password shouidn't be empty";  
                }
            }
            else
            {
                login.cancel();
                login.send();
            }


        }
        protected function button1_mouseOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            Mouse.cursor=MouseCursor.ARROW;
        }

        protected function button1_mouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            Mouse.cursor=MouseCursor.BUTTON;    
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:HTTPService id="login" url="http://192.168.1.4:8400/myapp/login" method="POST" result="login_resultHandler(event)">
        <s:request xmlns="">
            <myname>{user.text}</myname>
            <passwd>{pass.text}</passwd>
        </s:request>
        </s:HTTPService>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:BorderContainer x="0" y="-1" width="100%" height="100%" id="bordercontainerlogin" backgroundColor="#fa0000" backgroundAlpha=".2">
    <s:ModuleLoader id="modulerload"/>
    <s:Panel width="257" height="205" fontWeight="bold" horizontalCenter="-44" verticalCenter="-56" id="loginpanel" visible="true" title="User Login">


        <s:TextInput id="user" y="61"  horizontalCenter="-3" text="User name" focusIn="user_focusInHandler(event)" focusOut="user_focusOutHandler(event)"/>
        <s:TextInput id="pass" y="99" focusIn="pass_focusInHandler(event)"
                     focusOut="pass_focusOutHandler(event)" horizontalCenter="-3" text="Password"/>

        <s:Button y="137" label="LOGIN" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" horizontalCenter="-4"
                  mouseOut="button1_mouseOutHandler(event)"
                  mouseOver="button1_mouseOverHandler(event)"/>
        <s:Label id="validation" x="4" y="167" color="#D90D0D"/>

    </s:Panel>
    <!--<s:ComboBox id="resultData" dataProvider="{reg.lastResult.status}" visible="true" selectedIndex="0"/>-->
    <s:TextInput id="har" x="43" y="149" text="{login.lastResult.status}" visible="false" />
    </s:BorderContainer>
           </s:Module>
```

**module2.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <s:Module xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300" creationComplete="module1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

        var username:String;
        protected function getbalance_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            username= this.loaderInfo.url.toString();
            getbalance.cancel();
            getbalance.send();

        }

        protected function module1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:HTTPService id="getbalance" url="http://192.168.1.4:8400/myapp/getbalance" method="POST" result="getbalance_resultHandler(event)">
        <s:request xmlns="">
            <myname>{username}</myname>

        </s:request>
    </s:HTTPService>

</fx:Declarations>
<s:Label text="welcome {username}" id="welcomelabel" />
<s:TextInput text="{getbalance.lastResult.status}" id="balance"/>


   </s:Module>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Because module2 is creationComplete in this time,So,you can Because module2 is creationComplete in this time,So,you can be in when login_resultHandler load module2

Comment: sorry i didn't get it